# terminal mac - bash command not found, permission denied and '&gt' in prompt

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, permission

I tried to change colours in Terminal following this guide:

```
  http://voidcanvas.com/ubuntu-like-mac-terminal/
```

I created bash_profile file, saved and quitted Terminal. Now when i open Terminal I get this

```
Last login: Mon Oct 17 01:36:24 on ttys000
-bash:  : command not found
-bash:  : command not found
-bash:    git: command not found
-bash: gt: command not found
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
->> $
```

the last line is changed in StackExchange's text editor, I do not understand why please look at the uploaded photo below - this is how it looks in my terminal

I deleted bash_profile and I still get the same.

[image: Stupid screen shot]

Every command I write is followed by:

```
-bash:    git: command not found
-bash: gt: command not found
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
```

What should I do it to stop it?

Update from comments: Here's what I put in the file.

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxBxCxDxexegedabagaced
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2&gt; /dev/null |
    sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* (.*)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\e[0;35m-&gt;&gt; \e[1;34m\W\e[0;32m\$(parse_git_branch)\e[0;37m $ "
```

Comment: Note the file is not bash_profile but .bash_profile

Comment: Thank you Mark, I edited .bash_profile and it is back to default now. In my confusion I created two files .bash_profile and bash_profile. Any idea how to change my terminal look into ubuntu like style and colours without getting this weird messages?

Comment: The wierd messages are because you messed you PATH and are nothing tom do with prompt colours - there are other questions re coliours

Comment: can you give us the content of your .bash_profile? You can edit your first post and add the content there. I think there is something wrong in your profile.

Comment: thanks, I have noticed that I have had a wrong link to the article I have been using. I have edited my post and it shows the correct link. Could you please have a look at it and see why the recommended lines put into my .bash_profile are messing my path?

Comment: Using the article I wrote this into .bash_profile:              export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxBxCxDxexegedabagaced
 
parse_git_branch() {
   git branch 2&gt; /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
 
export PS1="\e[0;35m-&gt;&gt; \e[1;34m\W\e[0;32m\$(parse_git_branch)\e[0;37m $ "

Comment: Please ask a new question regarding the faulty color guide instead of spamming the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&gt;` is a syntax error, apparently caused by HTML markup in whatever source you copy/pasted this from.  Where you see `&gt;` the author intended `>` and where you see `&lt;` the author intended `<`.  If there's an `&amp;` that will need to be replaced with a literal `&` etc.

See a listing of HTML entity codes for a somewhat more exhaustive list.

Comment: There's a comment on the blog post about this as well, but it's rather obscurely phrased.